# Get a word's synonyms

Tags: nlp

Is there an API where for a given English word I can get a set of its synonyms?
If not synonyms, then at least words used in similar contexts.

My goal is to construct sentences with similar structure.

For instance, from this:

```
Jason found 49 seashells and 48 starfish
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
Joan grew 29 carrots and 14 watermelons
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) is your answer. You can call it in bash, or from Java, [etc](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/).

Comment: APIs link is dead. Here is an alternative: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/related-projects

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python then you can use **[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).** It has the most used **Wordnet** which can provide you with

- Synonyms
- Hyponyms
- Hypernyms
- Meronyms
- Holonyms